# Why isn't my PC recognizing my serial stream from my Arduino Uno?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, serial, data-acquisition

I installed the instrument control package to Octave and have the Arduino IDE sending a single character to the computer every 100 ms. The device is transmitting on COM3 but the software still doesn't recognize that COM3 is still being used and gives the message error "serial: Error opening the interface: No such file or directory". What could be the issue? I know my computer doesn't support GPIB.

Arduino Code:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
Serial.print('A');
delay(100);
}
```

Octave Code:

````
pkg load instrument-control

if (exist("serial") != 3)
    disp("No Serial Support");
endif

#s1 = serial("\\.\COM6")   % Open the port
pause(1);                    % Optional wait for device to wake up
testport=serial("COM6"); #open
pause(1);
#{
set(testport,'baudrate',9600);
set(testport,'bytesize',8);
set(testport,'parity','n');
set(testport,'stopbits',1);
set(testport,'timeout',50);
#}
```
````

Comment: You are trying to open COM6. Yet you say your device is on COM3. Could that be the issue?

Comment: probable wrong comm port or different baud rate.

Comment: COM3 was changed to COM6 to see if another COM port could be recognized. It couldn't.

Comment: `Arduino IDE sending a single character to the computer every 100 ms` ... that is absolutely incorrect, the Arduino IDE does not send serial data to the computer

Comment: does the Arduino IDE serial monitor show the data?

Comment: Is the Arduino IDE and all other programs that might use COM ports closed? Can other serial terminal programs detect that the port exists and can it be opened?